# Advice on how/where to place requires in own gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am going through the blog [Creating mountable Gem](http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2013-05-30-how-to-write-a-gem/):

> Its important to note that you should require your dependent gems explicitly in the root file of your gem. Say if your gem is named my_cool_gem, then you should have my_cool_gem.rb created inside lib folder. If your gem is dependent on strong_parameters, then you need to add these lines:

The author did not mention why it is required to have the dependent gems explicitly in the root file. Can some one explain why this needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just cleaner. What if you had `require` statements in various files scattered all over your gem? It'd be a mess to easily see all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

> Its important to note that you should require your dependent gems
>   explicitly in the root file of your gem.

It is not a strict statement that you have to conform to (to be fair to the author, the word is "should", not "must"). Some people prefer to take a different approach, and e.g. require dependencies only in parts of the library that use them.

However, you do need to consider:

- Execution order of `require` statements that define symbols used elsewhere. You cannot call a DSL method that sets up instance methods for you, if the gem that provides the method has not yet been `require`-d
- You should check that you really do `require` all correct the dependencies, and your gem functions correctly in projects that do not load them already.

With both of these in mind, it is often quickest and easiest to `require` dependencies early and and in a way that can be quickly viewed. So the advice is sound; as it was presented in a very short article, covering the statement with caveats and extra background would make the whole thing a lot less pithy.